# Network error unable to reach the server - wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Recently I got the error "Network error unable to reach the server" in my wordpress website's dashboard while accessing CiviCRM. I have php 7.0 verson.
How can I resolve this issue.

[image]

Comment: What is your Wordpress core version? Have you checked civicrm logs?

Answer (score 1):

Issue is resolved now...it was base url without www in civicrm.setting file.

Comment: Could you accept this (your) answer to flag that your question has been solved?